# WeekPart from 2 dates

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I would like to find out the week difference between 2 dates in order to find out who hasn't paid his bills yet.

After 4 weeks, my customers are required to pay their bills.

My own attempt was

```
Public Function WeekPart(ByVal u1 As Date, ByVal u2 As Date) As Integer

    Dim w1 As Integer = WeekCount(u1)
    Dim w2 As Integer = WeekCount(u2)

    Return (w2 - w1)

End Function
```

I think my approach is right, but I'm not sure about the WeekCount function.
It's just a mockup.

Can anybody help?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `DateDiff` function and check the number of days.

Comment: @One FineDay Can you make your comment your answer?

Comment: You need to very clear on how you define the "week difference". Are customers required to pay the bill by 28 days after the transaction, 29 days, the Saturday, Sunday or Monday following 28 days after the transaction, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DateDiff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) function and check the number of days.

```
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, startDate, endDate) > 28 Then
 'true
End If
```